# motion deblurring before motion estimation by using signal processing approaches

Tags: image-processing, signals

Does anyone know how signal processing can help in regard to reduce motion blur? or can you point me to some resources, books or papers?

Comment: Google for Wiener filter and/or deconvolution and/or motion blur and you'll find plenty of information. As it stands, your question is far too broad for SO.

Comment: The problem is that my knowledge in image processing is elementary so when I search for something through the internet I get more confused. Actually What I am going to do is to measure the motion blur in a video file. I want to use either spatial or frequency domain techniques to first measure the motion blur and then find a way to reduce it. I have found so many different articles but I do not know how and where to start.

Comment: It might be better [to ask on dsp instead](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a naive Motion Blur Kernel, You can build a paramerized model of the kernel (Radius and Angle).
Based on those parameters you'll see its Spectrum has special shape and more importantly special places where it has zeros.
Now, given an image and assuming it doesn't have zeros in its spectrum you can look at its spectrum and infer the parameters of the "Motion Blur Kernel".
Using this parameters build the spectrum of the kernel and use Wiener Filter to restore the original image.

This is a naive method bu where the assumptions are right, it works pretty well.